# How to clean the list of recent users via Google API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I've been searching Google API reference but didn't manage to find any way to clean the list of recent users.
I use logout API call ('https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout') but the next time I start logging in, I see the previous accounts.

Every time I have to click "Sign in with different account" and remove previous users manually. I would like to clean this list after I use logout call. Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible programmatically there is no API for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two ways of solving the problem:
1. Always uncheck Stay signed in checkbox when signing in.
2. Disable Account Chooser by navigating to https://www.google.com/accounts/optintoaccountchooser?optout=1

You can re-enable Account Chooser by navigating the same link without "?optout=1" parameter.

Source article: https://techjourney.net/disable-google-choose-an-account-sign-in-page/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the list of users is on the client side, as you are using a federated login method (i.e. you are not storing usernames/passwords and authenticating within your app), and is not specific to your application.

So, logging out is revoking the authentication of the current user to your specific application. This appears to be working properly as the next time you visit it is requiring the password to be re-entered. It's not, however, logging the person out of other applications that are using the same auth provider. You don't have the right from your application to invalidate other applications' sessions, nor the user list for that client that against the auth provider itself (which is being used, ostensibly, for other applications that are outside of your sphere of influence).

In your scenario, you're thinking about it as if the auth mechanism is only being used for your app (which, it might be in your usage, but since it's not a custom-built auth provider for just your app, you have to live with the federated login rules).